# Find vectors at angle intervals from a reference vector

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Referring to the figure, how can I find the vectors $V_1, V_2, V_3$ and so on that are subtended at an angle of $\theta$, $2\theta$, $3\theta$ and so on from $V_0$ respectively.

The knowns are co-ordinates of $O$, $\theta$ and direction vector $V_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a rotation of angle $\theta$ about the origin, the matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\\ \end{pmatrix}$$ will rotate any vector you operate on it with.

Comment: Agreed, but what if $O$ is not the origin? Should I translate the system to the origin and then apply the matrix, and translate back?

Comment: I think so, yes. You can use http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg for this